# Python eyed3 what tags are available?

Tags: python, id3, eyed3

is there a list of tags which you can extract with eyed3? Apart from the obvious ones such as artist, track etc what others are available? I found out through trail and error that Bitrate is actually

```
info.bit_rate
```

I can't seem to find a list in the documentation http://eyed3.nicfit.net/#documentation-index

Comment: Why not try `dir(audio_file.tag)`?

Comment: I think your `bit_rate` is only available for MP3 headers.  The standard tags are in the ID3 spec that is in the documentation page you link.  You can [have a look at the source](https://bitbucket.org/nicfit/eyed3/src/899a89a39b68de4d4cf3841d57cdb09243baf0b5/src/eyed3/mp3/headers.py?at=default) or, as suggested above - use the [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function on objects to see what attributes they contain.